# Keeping exactly one object set as true/active

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

Very often I find myself in a situation where I wish to keep exactly one object out of some collection active in Unity. This is equivalent to a situation where you have a large array of Booleans, and you always want exactly one of these to be true, and upon certain input, you might want the index of that true Boolean to change.

Now I know that the obvious solution to this is to just keep track of the index that is currently true, and if it's supposed to be changed, you set it to false, and set the desired index to true. But for whatever reason, I'm just afraid that something could eventually go wrong. I can't think of any reason this would happen (besides lacking thread safety, but that shouldn't be an issue in unity, at least if I'm not messing around with threads myself), but the result would be catastrophic, and the problem would never fix itself - once two Booleans are true, it might stay that way for a very long time. So just to be sure, I generally turn off all the Booleans first, and then turn on the desired one.

Are there any reasons to be afraid of this as much as I am? What are some potential problems in this situation using the "obvious" solution? More generally - is there much reason to worry about mechanical computer errors? What if for whatever reason some register somewhere fails, and writes a wrong value in a situation like this, and I end up with two Booleans that are true, and it never fixes itself. How come these sort of problems seemingly never happen, is it just the sheer unlikelihood of such a problem occurring? Does this problem or this topic of "very safe code" have some type of name?

**EDIT - some examples**

An example is the navigation/traversal of a menu that only has one interactive submenu at a time. You click a button, and an interactive submenu opens, and the previous menu stops being interactive (but might perhaps stay visible, and do various other things). The simplest method is to keep track of the currently interactive element, and just turn it off when some other element is meant to  be turned on. But if it ever happens for whatever reason that the current interactive menu doesn't get turned off in this step, we're left with two interactive menus, and opening further menus won't ever turn off the wrongly interactive one (could cause problems if at some point later a more recent menu will intersecting this wrongly interactive one). Turning off might generally fix the problem, but that's a different topic.

Another very similar example - suppose we have a finite state machine like menu - we might have a current menu (state), and input might change this. Doing a transition from one state to another could be done by just turning off the current one and turning on the next. But the same problem as described above could happen.

One sort of solution could be to instead use a reference to the current state. But this could be messy - you will have to implement your own sort of function to call on this reference that will have the desired effect. So if you want button interactivity on the current menu, you will have to write your own method that somehow calls all the things that would be called if it were interactive, as if the object was just an active, turned on object.

Maybe that's not a huge issue. Maybe if I just rename `Update()` to something else (thus the menus might not really do much by default), and call this `UpdateNew()` from the `current` reference each frame. Or I could just put an if statement inside the Update() and always check if `current == this`.

But I might just be overly scared - maybe I could assume that just turning off the current state and turning on the new one is perfectly safe.

Comment: What if you keep track of the index in an `int` variable ? It represents the only `true` value.

Comment: @Malphegal I can't really do that - the issue isn't "knowing" the index, it's the setting of the appropriate Boolean to true. The reason is that essentially I have a ton of objects, and I want one to be "turned on". I can't really do anything just through a reference to the desired object - the object has to be updated each frame.

Comment: One thing that I could do, is in each object update function, I simply check if the "current" reference is pointing to it, before actually running the update method. It seems a bit wasteful and messy though.

Comment: Will be that index allways the same? to declare it as const/static, and forget about possible execution errors (should be on compile if it is marked as const)?

Comment: @Lotan  No, the index will not be static, it will change at runtime, based on user input.

Comment: I'd be interested in at least 1 specific use case. This would help us evaluate if the current pattern is the most appropriate one in the first place. Outside that, you could have a static helper class which contains an object reference like `currentObject`, and each object has a Getter for the bool which returns `true` if `this == currentObject`... this would 100% guarantee only 1 max is ever true.

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I've added an example. Yes your solution would definitely work, but it's very similar to turning off all the objects. It would however let me keep the "turn off all objects" code outside of the "manager", and just keep in inside of the objects themselves, which seems neater.